# Samsung RV420 is compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, hardware, compatibility

I would like to know if the Notebook Samsung RV420 is compatible with Ubuntu 11.10. The processor is a Core i3 2310M with 4GB of RAM.

The hardware works properly with Ubuntu?

Anyone has this model? Or at least one similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be compatible, no problem.

*Have you tried booting from the live CD/USB yet?*

Comment: I just ordered the notebook right now, I need to wait for the delivery. When I have it I will update here with the results.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on the Samsung RV420 and all the hardware works flawless. Thanks.